# como eu arrumo o "Menu ficando por baixo do slide"

Tags: css, menu, dropdown

pessoal na onde eu estou errando :/ ... ?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates');

h2{
font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;

}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Book+Basic');
.numero{font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
    opacity: 0.6;
     font-size:medium;
    
}
.iframe-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 59.25%; /* Ratio 16:9 ( 100%/16*9 = 56.25% ) */
}
.iframe-container > *{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body{
    background-color:;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Brown Odontologia</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--- zoom desativado para o usuario -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!----fonts google------->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/js" href="js/alerta.js">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->

    <style>
        .bs-example {
            margin: 50px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body class="container">
    <!--------------------------------------------------------- Menu ------------------------------------------------------------>

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <header class="w3-panel w3-center w3-opacity" style="padding:1px 5px">
            <h1 class="w3-xlarge">BROWN ODONTOLOGIA</h1>
            <hr style="line-height:2px; boder:none; color:aquamarine; background-color:black; margin-top:10px;" />
            <h6>SEU SORRISO É NOSSA MISSÃO</h6>
            <hr style="line-height:2px; boder:none; color:aquamarine; background-color:black; margin-top:10px;" />
            <a href="#menu" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Quem Somos ?</a>
            <a href="#escolher" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Por que nos escolher ?</a>
            <a href="#especia" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Especialidades</a>
            <a href="#chegar" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Como chegar ?</a>

            <div class="w3-button">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-center dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contatos</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: white"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2" style="text-align:right"> <i class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="font-size:19px;color:#1BD741"></i> WhatsApp</div>
                    </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="position:">
                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2" style="text-align:right"> <i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size:19px;color:black"></i> WhatsApp</div>
                    </a>

                </div>

  </div>
        </header>
  
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
        });
    </script>
    <!----------------------------------------------------------Tabela de contatos-------------------------------------------------->


    <!---------------------------------------------------------------Slide--------------------------------------------------------->

    <br />
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="bd-example">
        <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>Fácil Acesso</h5>
                        <p>Como chegar ? </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>O que vale é a qualidade</h5>
                        <p>Venha Conhecer Nossos Planos</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Próximo </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só colocar um `z-index` no `header`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Brown Odontologia</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!--- zoom desativado para o usuario -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <!----fonts google------->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/js" href="js/alerta.js">


  <style>
    .bs-example {
      margin: 50px;
    }

    header {
      z-index: 10;
    }
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates');

h2{
font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;

}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Book+Basic');
.numero{font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
opacity: 0.6;
font-size:medium;

}
.iframe-container{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 59.25%; /* Ratio 16:9 ( 100%/16*9 = 56.25% ) */
}
.iframe-container > *{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
body{

}
  </style>

</head>

<body class="container">
  <!--------------------------------------------------------- Menu ------------------------------------------------------------>

  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">

    <header class="w3-panel w3-center w3-opacity" style="padding:1px 5px">
      <h1 class="w3-xlarge">BROWN ODONTOLOGIA</h1>
      <hr style="line-height:2px; boder:none; color:aquamarine; background-color:black; margin-top:10px;" />
      <h6>SEU SORRISO É NOSSA MISSÃO</h6>
      <hr style="line-height:2px; boder:none; color:aquamarine; background-color:black; margin-top:10px;" />
      <a href="#menu" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Quem Somos ?</a>
      <a href="#escolher" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Por que nos escolher ?</a>
      <a href="#especia" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Especialidades</a>
      <a href="#chegar" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Como chegar ?</a>

      <div class="w3-button">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-center dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contatos</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: white"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2" style="text-align:right"> <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"
                style="font-size:19px;color:#1BD741"></i> WhatsApp</div>
          </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="position:">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2" style="text-align:right"> <i class="fa fa-phone"
                style="font-size:19px;color:black"></i> WhatsApp</div>
          </a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </header>

    <!----------------------------------------------------------Tabela de contatos-------------------------------------------------->


    <!---------------------------------------------------------------Slide--------------------------------------------------------->

    <br />
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="bd-example">
      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Fácil Acesso</h5>
              <p>Como chegar ? </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Second slide label</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>O que vale é a qualidade</h5>
              <p>Venha Conhecer Nossos Planos</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Próximo </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
      });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: mais como deixa o fundo branco (não acho q ficaria legal o fundo meio transparente)

Comment: @caiquesey cara até tentei ver aqui pq fica transparente, mas não consegui resolver... acho que vc poderia abrir outra pergunta para ver se aparece alguém com uma resposta para isso

Answer (score 0):

É, você pode usar o `z-indez` nas div's que você quer sobrepor, exemplo na `<header>`

```
header{
 z-index:2; /* Se der conflito você aumenta o número*/
}
```